# Filling gaps between data ranges in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an invoice table where I store invoices for given data ranges (i.e. invoice 1 for date between 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-31). Now it's possible for some days to not have invoices associated, so you would have

```
> ID | START_DATE | END_DATE
> ---------------------------- 
> 1  | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-31 
> 2  | 2012-02-05 | 2012-02-28
```

So in this case, 5 days from February will not have an invoice associated to them. For these days I want to estimate costs, so I need to somehow "get" these missing data ranges.

I've seen a few answers on SO with similar problems, but most of them rely on an additional calendar table which I cannot create.

Is there any other SQL solution, or would it be better to actually get invoices then calculate the gaps in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset has no overlapping dates, one solution is to use a query like this, that extracts all missing ranges:

```
select
  r1.END_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY d1, MIN(r2.START_DATE) - INTERVAL 1 DAY d2
from
  ranges r1 INNER JOIN ranges r2
  ON r1.END_DATE <= r2.START_DATE
group by
  r1.END_DATE
having
  DATEDIFF(MIN(r2.START_DATE), r1.END_DATE) > 1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d211a/2).

Comment: I know it wasn't part of the question though for future readers, this doesn't work if the dataset has overlapping dates. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ddcf/1) where I added the range `2012-03-14` to the `2012-03-17` and it incorrectly adds the 18th to the 20th as a gap where row #5 contradicts that with the 16th to the 19th being covered.

Comment: @Turnerj thank for your comment, you're right, I'll have to update my answer, better to specify that it won't work if the dataset has overlapping dates